# STL Metaprogramming - which types of my template class have been created at compile time?

Tags: c++, stl, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

First the apologies, i'm not sure if my question title even accuratly explains what I'm asking - I've had a look through google, but i'm not sure which terms I need in my search query, so the answer may be out there (or even on StackOverflow) already.

I have a templated class, which basically looks like the following - it uses the Singleton pattern, hence everything is static, I'm not looking for comments on why I'm storing the keys in a set and using strings etc, unless it actually provides a solution. There's a bit more to the class, but that isn't relevant to the question.

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass 
{
private:
  //Constructor and other bits and peices you don't need to know about
  static std::set<std::string> StoredKeys;
public:
  static bool GetValue(T &Value, std::string &Key)
  {
    //implementation
  }

  static SetValue(const T Value, std::string &Key)
  {
    //implementation
    StoredKeys.Insert(Key);
  }

  static KeyList GetKeys()
  {
    return KeyList(StoredKeys);
  }
};
```

Later on in some other part of the application I want to get all the Keys for all of the values - regardless of type.

Whilst I am fairly confident that at the moment only 3 or 4 types are being used with the class so I could write something like:

```
KeyList Keys = MyClass<bool>::GetKeys();
Keys += MyClass<double>::GetKeys();
Keys += MyClass<char>::GetKeys();
```

This will need to be updated each time a new type is used. It also has the downside of instantiating the class if it's not used anywhere.

I think (again I could be wrong) that metaprogramming is the answer here, some sort of macro maybe?

We're using boost, so I'm guessing the MPL library could be useful here?

This aspect of STL is a bit new to me, so I'm happy to read up and learn as much as I need, just as soon as I know exactly what it is I need to learn to engineer a solution.

Comment: You want to maintain a global list of all keys? You may as well either drop that into a global variable, or if you'd prefer, a static member of a superclass that MyClass inherits from.

Comment: What do you mean by "all types"? I think *that* aspect of your problem doesn't make sense. You can explicitly instantiate your template for all the primitive types, and write a self-registering helper class for all your user-defined types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `StoredKeys` into a non-template base class `class MyClassBase`, or add an `AllStoredKeys` static member to a non-template base class.

Alternatively, create a static init method called from `SetValue` that adds a pointer to `StoredKeys` to a static list.

Comment: Yup, seems kinda obvious now I think about it - I think I was too keen to start using template meta programming and therefore was thinking about over engineering a solution to the problem!

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic. If you need to enumerate all the types used to instantiate `MyClass` in your program, then you have to enumerate them explicitly, somewhere. somehow. And you have to manually update the list whenever it changes.

With template metaprogramming, the number of places you need to update manually can be reduced down to one, but you do need that one place.

Fortunately, in this particular problem you don't *need* to enumerate all the types. You just need to store all keys in one set, as opposed to splitting them between several sets. You may create a common non-template base to `MyClass` and add `static std::set<std::string> StoredKeys` there (or perhaps make it a `multiset` if there's a possibility of identical keys in different type-specific sets).

Answer (score 0):

The first answere: Its not possible!
Template classes dont actually have a "generics" in common (like in java) but a separate classes which dont have anything to do with eachother.

The second answere: Theres a workaround. One can define a base class `MyClassBase` which defines properties shared by all templated subclasses. The problem is that you have a singleton pattern here which might makes the situation a bit more compilcated. I think a solution might look like this:

```
class MyClassBase {
  static std::vector<MyClassBase*> childs;

  static KeyList getAllKeys(){
       //iterate over childs here and call ->GetKeys
  }

  virtual KeyList GetKeys() = 0;

  template<typename T>
  static T* instance() {
     T* instance = MyClass<T>::instance();
     if(std::find(childs.begin(), childs.end(), instance) != childs.end()){
       childs.push_back(instance);
     }
     return instance;
  }
};
```

Please forgive me any syntactic errors; I just typed that in the Stackoverflow editor, but i think it should make my point clear.

**Edit:**
I just saw that I named the singleton method of the subclasses also `instance()`. This will probably not work. Give it some other name like `privateInstance()` or so. Then you must change `T* instance = MyClass<T>::instance();` to `T* instance = MyClass<T>::privateInstance();`